# How to show all colors of linear-gradient

Tags: html, css, angular

as shown in the css section below, i have the linear-gradient and it has the specified colors.the problem is what i am getting is what being displayed on the image below.
the highest value of the linear-gradient is hsl(16.94, 100%, 50%), while as the image shows, the highest value on the legend in not hsl(16.94, 100%, 50%) because hsl(16.94, 100%, 50%) is almost red while the highest value on the legend bar is
75 with another color.

please let me know why hsl(16.94, 100%, 50%) is not shown on the legend and is it possible to stretch the colors on the legend bar so i can see each color distinctly

**css**:

```
linearColorsGradient{
background: linear-gradient(to right,
hsl(50.82, 100%, 50%),hsl(50.12, 100%, 50%),hsl(49.18, 100%, 50%),hsl(48.47, 100%, 50%),hsl(47.76, 100%, 50%),hsl(47.06, 100%, 50%),hsl(46.12, 100%, 50%),hsl(45.41, 100%, 50%),hsl(44.71, 100%, 50%),
hsl(43.76, 100%, 50%),hsl(43.06, 100%, 50%),hsl(42.12, 100%, 50%),hsl(41.41, 100%, 50%),hsl(40.47, 100%, 50%),hsl(39.76, 100%, 50%),hsl(38.82, 100%, 50%),hsl(38.12, 100%, 50%),hsl(37.18, 100%, 50%),
hsl(36.47, 100%, 50%),hsl(35.53, 100%, 50%),hsl(34.82, 100%, 50%),hsl(33.88, 100%, 50%),hsl(32.94, 100%, 50%),hsl(32.00, 100%, 50%),hsl(31.29, 100%, 50%),hsl(30.35, 100%, 50%),hsl(29.41, 100%, 50%),
hsl(28.47, 100%, 50%),hsl(27.53, 100%, 50%),hsl(26.59, 100%, 50%),hsl(25.65, 100%, 50%),hsl(24.71, 100%, 50%),hsl(23.53, 100%, 50%),hsl(22.59, 100%, 50%),hsl(21.41, 100%, 50%),hsl(20.47, 100%, 50%),
hsl(19.29, 100%, 50%),hsl(18.12, 100%, 50%),hsl(16.94, 100%, 50%)
);
```

**legend**:

[image]

Comment: maybe i have become colorblind or dont understand your question. but the colors you put in the css matches what shown. do you mean it needs to be more red? cause if you want complete red its `hsl( 4, 100%, 50%)`

Comment: Could you describe a bit more what you mean by 'see each color distinctly', Do you want definite stripes of each of those colors without the blending?

Comment: @AHaworth yes please, is it possible?

Comment: Yes you can make them into stripes but the result is almost indistinguishable from the continuous blending you already have. This is because there are so many colors that each takes up only just over 2% of the width of the element. I did it on a full screen see https://i.stack.imgur.com/zvVYV.png  If you want stripes that the user can see you need to think about fewer colors - what is it you actually want to mark in this way.